# fix the image size oncustom tabelview I am using the cell.imageview property

Tags: iphone

I am using the custom tabelview cell when I show the images on tabelview cell than all images size is different how to show all the images of same size in iphone

```
  NSString *str=[self.uploadimagearry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSURL *uploadimageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   // NSData *imgdata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:uploadimageURL];

    //UIImage * uploadimage = [UIImage imageWithData:imgdata];
    cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, -15, 40, 35);
    //[[cell imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        cell.autoresizesSubviews=NO;

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:uploadimageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text=[imageidarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the contentMode property on the UIImageViews to one of UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill...

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```